# Change TEXT color on line X in TrichEdit

Tags: delphi-7

I run Delphi 7 on XP sp3.

In my TrichEdit I have N lines like this:

```
TextLine 1
TextLine 2
..
TextLine N 
...
```

If, for some reason the an error ocur, and the text changes to:

```
TextLine 1
TextLine 2
TextLine 2   (mark // my marking)
..
TextLine N
```

I want the first duplicate (= second line Textline 2 (mark) ) marked as RED.

I have tried to :

```
Text := RichEdit.Lines[second Textline 2];
Richedit.SelAttributes.Color := clRed; 
RichEdit.SelText := Text;
```

It works but places the Text at the beginning (topline in the RichEdit).

I see the problem as moving the RichEdit-lineCounter to line (testline 2 (mark)) or something similar, but how do I do that (= mark the error-line in RED )  ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this following:

1. Find the character index of the first character whose formatting you want to change, and set `SelStart` to that index.
2. Set `SelLength` to be the length of the text that you wish to format.
3. Modify `SelAttributes` to apply the desired formatting.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that.

Comment: See the [`EM_LINEINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-lineindex) and [`EM_LINELENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-linelength) messages (note, there is a typo in the latter doc. "This parameter can be 1" should say "This parameter can be -1" instead).